# Managing plugins in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vim, plugin

## Vim-plug installation on Ubuntu 16.10

I'm a new user of Ubuntu, and I'd like a little bit of help with plugins.

According to this [website](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), I installed `vim-plug` with this command: `curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim`

I have also created the directory `~/.vim/plugged` as suggested. 
So far I know I have to install my plugins inside (in `~/.vimrc` file):

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

call plug#end()
```

It is indicated I have to make the content of "Download plug.vim" available inside the 'autoload' directory.

**Question 1:** What is the 'autoload' directory here?

In fact, I want to install `vim-plug` to install several plugins like `nerdtree`. The way I understand the procedure is to go over the website https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree, and take only the part `scrooloose/nerdtree` to install the plugin :

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

call plug#end()
```

then execute `:PlugInstall`.

**Question 2 :** Where do I have an issue (if there are any)?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question but from Vim 8.0 (which will be in Ubuntu 17.04), there will be a built-in package manager. Then you'll only need to throw things to $VIM/pack. Read more here: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/repeat.txt#L459

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a VIM plugin manager like "Pathogen". They will simplify the management of plugins. Here is excerpt from `vim-pathogen` site.

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
```

Add to your `.vimrc`

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

In case you are confused about path of `.vimrc`, you can run this command in `vim'

```
:e $MYVIMRC
```

To add plugins, you can do

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-rails.git
git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-bundler.git
```

You can read more about Pathogen here

https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen